# Equivalent of z-score in exponential distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exponential-family, z-statistic

I have an exponentially distributed set of data, but there are a number of outliers at the margin. If I want to identify samples above the mean that I am 99.9+% confident are not the result of sampling error, how do I do this? In a normal distribution I can, of course, calculate the number of standard deviations and then find the number of SDs above mean required to meet my confidence criteria. Is there a similar process for exponential distributions?

Answer (score 4):

> If I want to identify samples above the mean that I am 99.9+% confident are not the result of sampling error, how do I do this?

Unless you have some statistical knowledge about the source of these outliers, you can't claim this. To simplify a little bit, outliers filtering just getting rid of the most extreme data points.

In your case you want to get rid of the 0.1% most extreme data points. To answer **this** question:

1. Find $X_0$ such as $P(X>X_0)=0.1%$
2. Discard every data point superior to $X_0$.

You do not need any table to compute $X_0$ as the cumulative distribution function of the exponential distribution is computable.
Let be λ the parameter of your exponential distribution
$P(x>X_0)=e^{−λX_0}=0.1$ implies that $X_0=\frac{-ln(0.1)}{λ}$

To get back to your misconception (or just vocabulary slippery, who knows). Let's say you have N=10,000. If there are no real outliers, statistically speaking you will still get rid of something around 10 data points (which are 100% **not** outliers).

Comment: Thanks! That's the issue I'm concerned with--I don't want to simply remove the top x records; I want to identify a cutoff point that gives me a level of confidence that they come from a separate distribution from the other observations. 

Assuming I don't know the lambda of my distribution, is the best option to estimate it and then plug that into the CDF?

Comment: If you have a good reason to assume that your outliers comes from a known distribution, there is something you can do, but I would suggest to ask another to give more details about this distribution. For your second question, have a look on this section on the dedicated wikipedia page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Parameter_estimation basically you can take the mean of your data points for an unbiased estimator of 1/λ but there are some subtleties.